# Maya - Exported .FBX is without smoothening after binding the skin

Tags: maya

I have a problem. I'm creating a character for my game. Everything is fine until I will not bind the skin to my character. After binding the skeleton to the skin, when I'm exporting my character to .FBX it's without smoothing. It looks exactly the same when I press 1 on my keyboard inside Maya. Before binding, everything is exporting as it should (smoothed). I've used Game Exporter and Send to Unreal options - both with the same result

Comment: Generally this is a place to ask programming rather than end-user questions.  That said, the first thing I'd try is to delete the history on that mesh before binding the skin

Comment: Okay, sorry. Unfortunately, it didn't work

Comment: Another next step would be to delete history force all normals to smooth, and then delete again.  You may have normals that are locked in place and need to be fused.  Or, you may have disjoint verts that look fine until the mesh moves; a merge vertices with a very small tolerance might also help